# Is there a simpler way to iterate thru a 2-D array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a code like this:

```
for i = 2:3:11
    for j = 2:3:11
     % some code 
    end
end
```

Which is iterates through an array (for example A) by a "3-by-3" matrix. And I'm wondering, is there a simpler solution to do this, like the

```
A = [2:11,2:11];
```

command?

The solution

```
A(2:3:11,2:311)
```

is working perfectly, thank you guys, but what if the exact code is like this:

```
 for i = 2:3:11
    for j = 2:3:11
       a = i-1:i+1;
       b = j-1:j+1;
       R = img(a,b);
       I = mean(mean(R));
       % some more code
    end
end
```

?

So I not only want those elements but to work with all the 9 elements. (The one with the exact position and the 8 right around them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A(2:3:11,2:3:11)
```

Will return exactly the matrix with the elements that you looped over in your first code example.

You can also Modify your Matrix A like so:

```
A(2:3:11,2:3:11) = A(2:3:11,2:3:11)*2;
```

What is most elegant depends on what you want to do with the elements. Matlab supports many matrix/vector commands that can greatly speed up the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a subset of `A`:

```
B = A(2:3:11, 2:3:11)
```

The dimensions of `A` must be at least 11x11 in this example.

Comment: It also returns the elements A(2,5), A(2,8), A(2,11), A(5,8) etc.

Comment: Of course, my bad. Thanks for the hint. But this is what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

*generally* speaking I don't think it gets any simpler.

But maybe you can give it some structure so it will be cleaner/easier to work with.

Useful commands for this would be `reshape` or `mat2cell`

eg this would turn it into a cell where the 3x3 matrices are already grouped.

```
a = rand(11,11)
eg = mat2cell(a,[1,3,3,3,1],[1,3,3,3,1])
```

or even arrange them in a 4d array (if you are comfortable with that many dimensions...)

If you think about losing one of the `for` loops you could experiment with [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) (`ind2sub` and `sub2ind` are for this).

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function that accepts a block of that size, and either returns a scalar, or another block of the same size, like so:

```
function pro = process_block (blk)
  %% blk.data will be a 3x3 block, code that process goes here. You
  %% can make it return a scalar or another matrix of the same size
  pro = mean (blk.data(:));
end
```

Then use `blockproc` with the block size you want:

```
B = blockproc (A(2:11,2:11), [3 3], @process_block);
```